# ASP.Net MVC FormsAuthentication - ability to disable user while using a "remember me" persistent cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I'm using the built-in `Membership` for logins with FormsAuthentication. I want allow the administrator disable other user accounts, I've thought of changing the `IsApproved` property of the user to false, but it didn't work and still showed the user as logged in. I figure this happened because of the persistent cookie I've previously set with `SetAuthCookie` for the user.

I've looked into `FormsAuthenticationTicket` and `SetAuthCookie`, I can't seem to find how to re-validate them occasionally against the repository to make sure the user still exists/is active.

Is this covered by the existing functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how your authentication pipeline works, here is a general idea:
with every request get the data for the user from DB:

```
public User CurrentUser
        {
            get
            {
                if (_CurrentUser == null && Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    //your method to get the user
                    _CurrentUser = _UserRepository.GetUserByEmail(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name); 
                }
                return _CurrentUser;
            }
        }
```

Then with an ActionFilter you can check:

```
 protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            //user enabled?
            if (CurrentUser != null && !CurrentUser.IsApproved)
            {
                //Force LogOut
                //Redirect to LogOut
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary {{ "Controller", "Account" },
                                      { "Action", "LogOff" } });
            }
}
```

Comment: I hoped that there are ways to configure the existing authentication system to check periodically for the validity of the login cookie/ticket. If such a feature doesn't exist, I hope to find a good suggestion on where to store the last "validity check" date (I can't trust the cookie for that, and the last login date is not accessible in the `HttpContext.User` object.

Comment: I usually use a custom membership implementation so that how i tend do it but maybe you can hook to something like `HttpApplication.AuthenticateRequest` Event, in your global.asax check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947413/asp-net-mvc-1-using-persistent-cookie-intercept-loading-of-user-data-to-include?rq=1